# Gstreamer:dynamically link realize

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have a problem like this [problem](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GStreamer-C-Code-to-play-video-td3715064.html) !

I'm confused how to realize dynamically link with "qtdemux" element and "decoder" element?

the command line is works well. and when with code

when run

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/root/park-h264.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapisink
```

it works well, but when I compile and run the following code, it failed.

```
if (!gst_element_link(demux, decoder))
  printf("link demux-decoder fail\n");
```

Is there any examples or specification? Thanks for u help!

Comment: Is there anyone that speaks better english that can help you with your question?  I can't understand what you're asking because the words don't make any sense.

Comment: @xaxxon I just change the question. my problem is there any examples of dynamically link. just like the [problem](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GStreamer-C-Code-to-play-video-td3715064.html) mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolve this problem. with [this page](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-pads.html) help

the following code

```
GstElement *filesrc, *demux, *decoder, *sink;
static void
cb_new_pad (GstElement *element,
            GstPad     *pad,
            gpointer    data)
{
    gchar *name;

    name = gst_pad_get_name (pad);
    if (strcmp (name, "video_0") == 0 &&
        !gst_element_link_pads(demux, name, decoder, "sink")) {
        printf("link demux-decoder fail\n");
    }
    g_free (name);
}
static void
pipeline_init(char *data)
{
   filesrc = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "filesrc");
   demux = gst_element_factory_make ("qtdemux", "qtdemux");
   decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("vaapidecode", "decoder");
   sink = gst_element_factory_make ("vaapisink", "sink");

   if (!filesrc || !demux || !decoder || !sink)
       return;

   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filesrc), "location", data, NULL);

   if (!gst_element_link(filesrc, demux)) {
       printf("link filesrd--demux fail\n");
       return;
   }
   if (!gst_element_link(decoder, sink)) {
       printf("link decoder--sink fail\n");
       return;
   }

   g_signal_connect (demux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (cb_new_pad), NULL);

}
```